# Can I bring System Unit (CPU) from Philippines to Malaysia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, malaysia, import-taxes

Will Malaysia customs allow me to enter Kuala Lumpur with my system unit/CPU?

Comment: Are you talking about an actual CPU (small chip) or an entire desktop computer (which some people insist on calling a "CPU")? For what purpose are you bringing the CPU with you?

Comment: OK, Googling "System Unit" led me to understand that this is an actual desktop computer [image here](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS64n6FA54czM1l4p_R800E8Mth9BtHJku-MA&usqp=CAU), not a "CPU" [image here](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQwkqRxF2Y_HLq9fdiDuJlnFLS5PRMcZ5InHw&usqp=CAU). If my understanding is correct, you may want to [edit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/177284/edit) your question to make that clearer by replacing "System Unit (CPU)" with "desktop computer"

Comment: And arguably a laptop computer is really a System Unit/CPU + Display + Keyboard all in one handy portable device, which is routinely carried by travelers pretty much everywhere without a problem (can be issues of turn on to prove it is real, privacy issues, etc. but not a basic issue of possession). Presumably this is "desktop system unit" which *may* raise more questions as it is a little more unusual and can't as easily be verified to be a functioning computer.

Comment: I voted to reopen. The OP has not returned to tell us what they mean by "System Unit (CPU)." Thus, we're still guessing. A reasonable opportunity (a few days, say) should be allowed before closing.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica, OP can edit while closed, a long time is available for that.

Comment: @Willeke Thanks for the pointer. I've withdrawn my vote to reopen.